# Visual Studio 2015 error: exe_main.cpp not found

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, error-handling, fortran

I am new to using Visual studio for Fortran programming.
Just as I start to step into the line-by-line debugging of the code, an error occured, and it crashed out. The error informs that "exe_main.cpp" file could not be found.
Would you please guide me how can I overcome this problem?
Shall I download such a file and replace somewhere, or any other solution.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you run a Fortran program from Visual Studio, there is actually a C "wrapper" that calls the Fortran main program. What seems to have happened here is that your program finished execution, returned to the main() wrapper (exe_main.cpp) and got an error (perhaps because stack was corrupted or something else.)

You don't need the source to exe_main.cpp and should ignore that. If you can provide more details on "crashed out", we can probably help with that problem.